# How can i know the value or array which pass it in the form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have this problem and i don't how can i solve it.
I have a project that interactive with database and i make a CRUD html table for interact with, which mean i have 15 table in relative database and i want insert and delete and edit the records so this is my code.
my question is : how can i know when i insert values this values to this table for insert it to the same table in database i don't know really.

This is my controller :

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class Main extends CI_Controller {

```
function index($some) 
{

    $this->load->model('main_model');
    switch ($some) {
        case 'class':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'ClassID' => 'class id',
                'ClassNum' => 'class name',
                'ClassSize' => 'class size',
                'Floor' => 'floor'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getClass();
            break;
        case 'group':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'GroupID' => 'id',
                'GroupNum' => 'group name',
                'SectionNum' => 'section',
                'YearNum' => 'year',
                'ProfNameAra' => 'proffetion name'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getGroupSection();
            break;
        case 'hole':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'HoleID' => 'id',
                'HoleNum' => 'hole name',
                'HoleSize' => 'hole size',
                'Floor' => 'floor'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getHole();
            break;
        case 'lab':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'LabID' => 'id',
                'LabName' => 'lab_name',
                'LabSize' => 'lab_size',
                'Floor' => 'floor'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getLab();
            break;
        case 'lecture':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'LectureID' => 'id',
                'SubjectAra' => 'subject name',
                'Is_Lecture' => 'yes/no',
                'YearNum' => 'year',
                'ProfNameAra' => 'proffission',
                'SubjectSemester' => 'semester'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getLectureSubject();
            break;
        case 'prof':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'ProfID' => 'id',
                'ProfNameAra' => 'prof name'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getProf();
            break;
        case 'section':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'SectionID' => 'id',
                'SectionNum' => 'section name',
                'YearNum' => 'year',
                'ProfNameAra' => 'proffission'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getSection();
            break;
        case 'subgroup':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'SubgroupID' => 'id',
                'SubgroupNum' => 'section name',
                'GroupNum' => 'group name',
                'SectionNum' => 'section name'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getSubgroup();
            break;
        case 'subject':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'SubjectID' => 'id',
                'SubjectAra' => 'subject name',
                'Is_Lecture' => ' yes/no',
                'YearNum' => 'year',
                'ProfNameAra' => 'proffission'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getSubject();
            break;
        case 'teacher':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'TeacherID' => 'id',
                'TeacherName' => 'teacher name'
            );
           $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getTeacher();
            break;
        case 'timetable':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'TimetableID' => 'id',
                'YearDate' => 'date',
                'Semester' => 'semester',
                'YearNum' => 'year',
                'ProfNameAra' => 'proffission',
                'SectionNum' => 'sectin name'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getTimetable();
            break;
        case 'timetabledetail':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'DetailID' => 'id',
                'Day' => 'day',
                'Period' => 'period',
                'YearDate' => 'year date',
                'Semester' => 'semester',
                'YearNum' => 'year',
                'ProfNameAra' => 'proffission',
                'SectionNum' => 'section name',
                'GroupNum' => 'group name',
                'SubgroupNum' => 'subgroup name',
                'LabName' => 'lab name',
                'HoleNum' => 'hole name',
                'ClassNum' => 'class name',
                'TeacherName' => 'teacher name',
                'SubjectAra' => 'subject name'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getTimetabledetail();
            break;
        case 'year':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'YearID' => 'id',
                'YearNum' => 'year'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getYear();
            break;
        case 'year_prof':
            $data['fields'] = array(
                'YearNum' => 'year',
                'ProfNameAra' => 'proffission'
            );
            $data['tables'] = $this->main_model->getYearProf();
            break;
    }



    $data['main_content'] = 'main';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
  }
}
```

and this is my view :

```
<?php echo form_open('main') ?>

    <table id="dg" title="Andro-CH Table" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
        url="get_users.php"
        toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
        rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
    <thead>
                <tr>
                <?php foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_display): ?>
                    <th field="<?php echo $field_name?>" width="50"> <?php echo $field_display; ?> </th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>    
    </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($tables as $table): ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_display): ?>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $table->$field_name; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>    
                </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
</table>
<div id="toolbar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onclick="newUser()">New User</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onclick="editUser()">Edit User</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true" onclick="destroyUser()">Remove User</a>
</div>

<div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:400px;height:280px;padding:10px 20px" closed="true" buttons="#dlg-buttons">
    <div class="ftitle">Table Information</div>
                <div class="fitem">
                    <?php foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_display): ?>
                        <?php echo form_label("$field_display:"); ?>
                        <?php echo form_input("$field_name", '', 'class="easyui-validatebox" required="true"'); ?>
                        <br>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
</div>
<div id="dlg-buttons">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-ok" onclick="saveUser()">Save</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-cancel" onclick="javascript:$('#dlg').dialog('close')">Cancel</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url;
    function newUser(){
        $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','New User');
        $('#fm').form('clear');
        url = 'save_user.php';
    }
    function editUser(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit User');
            $('#fm').form('load',row);
            url = 'update_user.php?id='+row.id;
        }
    }
    function saveUser(){
        $('#fm').form('submit',{
            url: url,
            onSubmit: function(){
                return $(this).form('validate');
            },
            success: function(result){
                var result = eval('('+result+')');
                if (result.errorMsg){
                    $.messager.show({
                        title: 'Error',
                        msg: result.errorMsg
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#dlg').dialog('close');      // close the dialog
                    $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function destroyUser(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to destroy this user?',function(r){
                if (r){
                    $.post('destroy_user.php',{id:row.id},function(result){
                        if (result.success){
                            $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                        } else {
                            $.messager.show({   // show error message
                                title: 'Error',
                                msg: result.errorMsg
                            });
                        }
                    },'json');
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #fm{
        margin:0;
        padding:10px 30px;
    }
    .ftitle{
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:5px 0;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .fitem{
        margin-bottom:5px;
    }
    .fitem label{
        display:inline-block;
        width:80px;
    }
</style>
```

and this is my model it doesn't complete yet

```
<?php

class Main_model extends CI_Model {

function getClass() {

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('class')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getGroup() {

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('group')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getGroupSection() {
    $q = $this->db->select('group.GroupID, group.GroupNum, section.SectionNum,year.YearNum,prof.ProfNameAra')
            ->from('group')
            ->join('section', 'group.Section_id = section.SectionID')
            ->join('year', 'year.YearID = section.Year_id')
            ->join('prof', 'section.Prof_id =  prof.ProfID');
    return $q->get()->result();
}

function getHole() {

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('hole')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getLab() {

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('lab')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getLecture() {

    $query = $this->db->select()
            ->from('lecture')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getLectureSubject() {
    $q = $this->db->select('lecture.LectureID, subject.SubjectAra, subject.Is_Lecture, year.YearNum, prof.ProfNameAra, subject.SubjectSemester')
            ->from('lecture')
            ->join('subject', 'lecture.Subject_id = subject.SubjectID')
            ->join('prof', 'prof.ProfID = subject.Prof_id')
            ->join('year','year.YearID = subject.Year_id');

    return $q->get()->result();
}

function getProf() {

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('prof')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getSection() {

    $query = $this->db->select('section.SectionID, section.SectionNum, year.YearNum, prof.ProfNameAra')
            ->from('section')
            ->join('year', 'section.Year_id = year.YearID')
            ->join('prof', 'section.Prof_id = prof.ProfID')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getSubgroup() {

    $query = $this->db->select('subgroup.SubgroupID, subgroup.SubgroupNum, group.GroupNum, section.SectionNum')
            ->from('subgroup')
            ->join('group', 'subgroup.Group_id = group.GroupID')
            ->join('section', 'group.Section_id = section.SectionID')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getSubject() {

    $query = $this->db->select('subject.SubjectID,subject.SubjectAra,subject.SubjectSemester,subject.Is_Lecture,
        year.YearNum,prof.ProfNameAra')
            ->from('subject')
            ->join('year', 'year.YearID = subject.Year_id')
            ->join('prof', 'prof.ProfID = subject.Prof_id')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getTeacher() {

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('teacher')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getTimetableDetail() {

    $query = $this->db->select('DetailID,Day,Period,
        timetable.TimetableID,timetable.YearDate,timetable.Semester,
        year.YearNum,
        prof.ProfNameAra,
        section.SectionNum,
        group.GroupNum,
        subgroup.SubgroupNum,
        lab.LabName,
        hole.HoleNum,
        class.ClassNum,
        teacher.TeacherName,
        subject.SubjectAra')
            ->from('timetabledetail')
            ->join('timetable','Timetable_id = TimetableID')
            ->join('year', 'timetable.Year_id = year.YearID')
            ->join('prof', 'prof.ProfID = timetable.Prof_id')
            ->join('section', 'section.SectionID = timetable.Section_id')
            ->join('group', 'GroupID = Group_id')
            ->join('subgroup','SubgroupID = Subgroup_id')
            ->join('lab','LabID = Lab_id')
            ->join('hole', 'HoleID =Hole_id')
            ->join('class','ClassID = Class_id')
            ->join('teacher','TeacherID = Teacher_id')
            ->join('subject','SubjectID = Subject_id')
            ->get();

    return $query->result();
}

function getTimetable() {

    $query = $this->db->select('timetable.TimetableID,timetable.YearDate,timetable.Semester,
        year.YearNum,
        prof.ProfNameAra,
        section.SectionNum')
            ->from('timetable')
            ->join('year', 'timetable.Year_id = year.YearID')
            ->join('prof', 'prof.ProfID = timetable.Prof_id')
            ->join('section', 'section.SectionID = timetable.Section_id')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getYear() {

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('year')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getYearProf()
{
    $q = $this->db->select('year.YearNum, prof.ProfNameAra')
            ->from('year_prof')
            ->join('year', 'year_prof.Year_id = year.YearID')
            ->join('prof', 'year_prof.Prof_id = prof.ProfID')
            ->get();

    return $q->result();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about sending the type of data also.

```
...
case 'case1':
 $data['table'] = $result..
 $data['table_type'] = 'case1';
break;
case 'case2':
 $data['table'] = $result..
 $data['table_type'] = 'case2';
break;
...
```

Then on your views you can put the `table_type` variable on to the **submit button**:

```
<input type="submit" name="<?=$table_type;?>" value="update">
```

or a **HIDDEN FIELD**

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$table_type;?>" value="TRUE">
```

Then on your controller where you receive the **POST** data you can verify it by:

```
if($this->input->post('case1'))
{
  //for case 1
  //insert/update to case1 table
}elseif($this->input->post('case2'){
  //for case 2
  //insert/update to case2 table
}else{
 //default
}
```

This is just a simple one, you can add more security or make the checking of POST values more dynamic.